# Stop virtualenv using global site-packages pip?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, homebrew, pythonpath

I'm using Python 2.7.14 installed through Homebrew on MacOS. How do I stop this happening?:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
New python executable in /private/tmp/venv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /private/tmp/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

What I expected

```
$ env -i PATH=/tmp/venv/bin pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /private/tmp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

EDIT: Solution related [Why does virtualenv inherit $PYTHONPATH from my shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583777/why-does-virtualenv-inherit-pythonpath-from-my-shell)

Comment: What version of virtualenv are you on? (--no-site-packages is now the default behaviour so it shouldn't be needed)

Comment: virtualenv 15.1.0. Yeah I just wanted to be super sure that no site packages were being used.

Comment: I have the exact same setup as you and it works perfectly fine for me. For a second I thought it was some weird conflict with `/private/tmp` but I just don't get the same problem

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` say when you're in the virtualenv?

Comment: `pip` is special, virtualenv creates a copy of that even if you use `--no-site-packages`

Comment: Figured it out. Had to `unset PYTHONPATH` in my bin/activate

Answer (score 1):

I edited `venv/bin/activate` with this line:

```
unset PYTHONPATH
```